# How to change Display color settings Ubuntu?

Tags: graphics, display, colors

On Windows I have an "Intel HD Graphics Control Panel" that allows me to change the screen's color settings (brightness, contrast, hue, saturation etc.) I was looking for a similar tool on Ubuntu but could not find anything. Is there something similar available on Linux?

[image]

Comment: `gnome-control-center color &` ?

Comment: Oh, thank you! Didn't know about that